# How to decide figure placement specifier for the entire document

Tags: positioning

For figures there is posible to add placement spesifer like the following:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
  \includegraphics{/path/to/figure}
  \caption{}
  \label{}
\end{figure}
```

Where `[H]` is the placement specifier that places the figure "here" relative to the text. How can I decide this of an entire document, is there any usepackages, etc?

Comment: you can specify the default placement specifiers, eg make `ht` the default or whatever you need, but `H` is rather special it makes the figure a non-float, so it may not be set by the usual default mechanism

Comment: How would i specify the default placement specifier @DavidCarlisle?

Comment: `\renewcommand\fps@figure{ht}`  (in a package or after `\makeatletter`)

Comment: the only reason to use `figure` is to specify the content as a float, so `[H]` (which just redefines it to be a non-float) is a very odd construct really and not normally recommended (I say that as it was my idea:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle yes you are right, looked in to it and it does make more sense with `ht` instead if `H`. `\renewcommand\fps@figure{ht}` worked fine, thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as David suggested this can be done with the following command:

```
\makeatletter
% Make all figure use 'ht' position by default:
\renewcommand\fps@figure{ht}
\makeatother
```

As he said it´s generally not recommended to use the `H`, instead use `ht`.